# Insert if not exist - lookup by all columns

Tags: mysql

I want to insert new row without duplicates.

Whole idea is to insert new row only if indentical **pair** does not exist already, **not just one key**, meaning both columns must exist together to call it a duplicate.

```
 parent_id | report_date
 1         | 2015-12-15
 1         | 2015-10-10
(1         | 2015-10-10) NOT ALLOWED  
 2         | 2011-05-04
```

Comment: Create a candidate key and enforce a unique constraint.  Unique key = parent_Id + report_Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: Add Unique Index**

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`parent_id`, `report_date`);
```

Now if you tried to update, query execution will fail.

**Method 2: Check while inserting**

Best solution is to add unique index as suggested by @pyNoob in comments. But say if you can't do that, may be worried about disk space because of indexing?, then following query will work:-

```
INSERT INTO tablename (parent_id, report_date)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '1', '2015-10-10') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT parent_id, report_date FROM tablename where parent_id = '1' and report_date = '2015-10-10'
) LIMIT 1;
```